# bios settings changes giving cmos error if shutdown by empty battery or by pressing power key for long time

Tags: 16.04, uefi, windows-10, bios

I have dual BOOT Windows 10 & Ubuntu 16.04 in UEFI mode and secure boot off.
Due To degrading of my laptop's battery, system shutdowns(not properly but same as if pressing power button for a long time) on low battery without giving warning. Then when i switch on it gives me CMOS error and when i check the bios, the setting changes automatically to default and boot option show legacy mode. Any Solution? Same Happens In windows also.

Comment: Check your manufacturer's Web site for a firmware update. (They probably call it a "BIOS update" or something similar.) There's no guarantee that this will help, but it's the first thing I'd try, given your symptoms. Note that applying such updates sometimes disrupts the boot process, so you may need to be ready with an emergency disk with [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) or my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) just in case.

Comment: there is no update available for my bios